# Dynamic datagrid, optional columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I know this question has been answered before but looking at most of them, they use code behind and I am under the understanding that is never ok in MVVM, also others use MVVM pattern.  I refuse to use a pattern as I want to learn from the ground up.  I am able to bind the ItemsSource correctly but how do I bind to the datagrid headers and such.

I would think this is common but what I want is to be able to have a "table" of data with headers.  I want the user to be able to right click in the header row and toggle columns off and on.  That part I am not as worried about figuring out how to do.

I am asking how to have a datagrid with dynamic columns/headers without codebehind or a framework.  I am not sure how to bind from the viewmodel to a datagrid.

Comment: WPF *is* a framework.  So is .NET.  Don't get caught up in "correctness;" use best practices, but temper them with some common sense.

Comment: I understand, I just don't want to fall into the trap of I don't know how to do this so I will just use a helper framework to do it for me.  I was meaning frameworks like MVVM light and such.

Comment: *"I am under the understanding that is never ok in MVVM"*, that is plain wrong. A correct statements would be that "it is rarely necessary".

Comment: HB is correct that it is rarely necessary to use code-behind in MVVM, but keep in mind that code-behind is absolutely OK if the code-behind relates to your View only. You typically do not ever need to reference your ViewModel or Models in the code-behind, but every once in a while it is necessary to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="256" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dgEmp" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="490"  ItemsSource="{Binding DeleteData,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="6,7,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remark" Binding="{Binding Remark,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Update" x:Name="btnUpdate"
                            Click="btnUpdate_Click"></Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

In this Example ItemSource of DataGrid is DeleteData which is one `ObservableCollection<Expense_Submit>`

Expense_Submit is one class in that i have defined all properties .it's look like

```
public class Expense_Submit
{


 private int _ID;

    private string _UserID;

    private string _Description;

    private string _Amount;

    private DateTime _Date;

    private string _Remark;


  }
```

Comment: Thanks, so I notice that you have Visibility="Hidden" for the ID Header.  How can I bind to the Visibility property in order to toggle columns on and off?

Comment: ya in datagrid i don't want to show that coloum so i set it hidden.

Comment: ohk you have to create one property like

Comment: So have a separate class that deals with which columns are visible and bind that to the visibility so I can turn it on and off. In the xaml I would have visibility="{Binding _UserIDIsVisible}" for the ID header?  And then in the view model I would have a singleton object for that view that has those properties and I could toggle them off and on and update the view?

Comment: yes if you have to turn on or off that Id Header column would bind with visibility property and it will change as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

For That You have to bind Visibility Property.

```
Visibility={binding IDVisibile,mode=TwoWay}
```

in your ViewModel Create one property

```
 private Visibility _IDVisibile;

            public Visibility IDVisibile
            {
                get { return _BorderVisibility; }
                set { _BorderVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IDVisibile"); }
            }
```

Comment: If you have the time, I can't get it to hide the column, I can see when hovering over the IDVisible in xaml that it is set to hidden and I call property changed, but the column never disappears, what could cause this?

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding CardID}" Width="25" Visibility="{Binding IDVisible,Mode=TwoWay"></DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: private Visibility _IDVisible;

Comment: public Visibility IDVisible
{
   get { return _IDVisible; }
   set { _IDVisible = value; VerifyPropertyName("IDVisible");       OnPropertyChanged("IDVisible"); }
}

Comment: have you bind that visibility property with same viewmodel?